# Where is path for database stored in vs2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have SQL server 2008 R2 as well as SQL 2012 installed on my machine. I want VS 2012 to use SQL server 2008 R2 but for some reason its using SQL server 2012. Is there any setting inside VS2012 that i can use to specify the database i want to use?

Comment: Not sure why this this was downgraded by someone before reading the question carefully. All i am asking is that when you try to connect to database from within VS 2012 for some reason it is using SQL 2012 database engine where i want to use SQL server 2008 R2. To be more specific, when i hit "add sql server" in SQL server Object Explorer, i see a "Connect To Server" dialog box that say SQL Server 2012. I want to use SQL server 2008 R2. Is there a way to do that? I have both version of SQL server installed on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try a connection string in a config file.

Comment: Please see my comments. Thanks for the reply to the question.